Type declaration in Hibernate 6
So I was upgrading my old application to Hibernate 6, I was able to get most of the code sorted.
But this one column type is causing a problem.
@Column(name = "JOB_ID", columnDefinition = "CHAR(36)")
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")
public UUID getJobId() {
    return jobId;
}

When I try to compile I always get this message:
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method type()
  location: @interface org.hibernate.annotations.Type

From all the docs that I have read, the UUIDCharType has been removed from Hibernate 6. And the exception is coming from type in the first place and not the camel case Type. Any pointers would be helpful here. But I was not able to find too much documentation on this.

Try using @JdbcType(VarcharType.class) (or whatever it is exactly I can’t remember correctly) as i think in hibernate 6 it treats UUIDs as a string and converts them back.
Alternatively you can create your own Converter class and auto apply it. Look at  @ConverterRegistration as that can be applied to all entities with UUIDs as their type as it would be tedious changing several classes…
